# Building a crossbrowser HTMLeditor

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cross-browser, html-editor

I have a HTML editor witch consist of an IFRAME (#Editor_editor), 2 buttons(Design view and HTML view) and a toolbar. I want this editor to run on this web-browsers(IE9, IE10, Firefox, Chrome and Mac Safari).

In my Editor.jQuery.js file I have a function *Edit_ChangeMode* witch is triggered when the Design view or HTML view button is pushed.
[image]

If I use .innerText property in IE9 you can see it jump to the anonymous function from script block(13). Why does this happen ?

.innerText property doesn't work on Firefox and if I use .textContent property, in IE9, it jump to the anonymous from the else clause of Edit_ChangeMode function.

**EDIT**: jQuery mode

If I use .text() and .html() propertis in the same function in the else clause the html is not rendered properly.
[image]

Q: How can I make this HTML editor cross-browser?

Comment: So is your question _just_ about the `innerText` and `textContent` browser compatibility issues or about cross-browser compatibility in general?

Comment: general compatibility. If have tried with .innerHTML and with .innerText.

Comment: I even tried with the jQuery properties .text() and .html() but got a different problem(I'll post soon a screen shot).